# Get posts by term slug only

Tags: custom-taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

What I'm looking to do is build a shortcode to that will display a list of posts based on the taxonomy slugs passed to it. But as far as I can tell, you can't use just a term's slug to pull posts in without having to also specify the taxonomy it's in.

Is it possible to get posts or other taxonomy based data (term meta, name, etc) with just the terms slug, and without the specific taxonomy it's in?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at source of [`get_term()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_term/) it does hard check for taxonomy and for good reasons (caching, collisions, etc).

I see two possible approaches:

- look for term in every appropriate taxonomy until you match
- try to query for term by `search` or `name__like` in multiple taxonomies using [`get_terms()`](http://queryposts.com/function/get_terms/) and work with results